# Integrate PayPal

Tags: html, redirect, paypal

I have successfully integrated PayPal. All is working fine. But I want my form to redirect to my site after a successful payment. Another question: how to get response from PayPal?
Here is my PayPal form. Thanks.

```
   `<form action="https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">  
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="savife_1314264698_biz@gmail.com ">  
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Alice's Weekly Digest">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="DIG Weekly">  
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">  
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://localhost/check.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://google.co.in">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00">  
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">  
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">  
    
    <!-- Display the payment button. -->  
    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="btn_subscribe_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">  
    <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >  
</form>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just go through this:

What you want is PAYPAL IPN, INSTANT PAYMENT NOTIFICATION which is sent to user's website after payment is completed.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro

or you can also set path to IPN in your cart where paypal will send notification like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="site.com/ipn/index.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="return"     value="site.com/ipn/index.php"/>
```

But you'll need to login to your merchant account on paypal to manually specify the ipn and auto return url. in website payment preferences and instant payment notifications section under profile tab.

Following i've added the sample ipn code which is sent to your website after successfull payment:

```
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
// check the payment_status is Completed
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
// check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
// process payment
}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation
}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

You need to add this code on your notify url page. the return page you mention in notify url field of shopping cart i.e.

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="site.com/ipn/index.php" />
```

Put this code in `site.com/ipn/index.php`

Lets take an example of your shopping cart:

```
<form action="https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">  
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="savife_1314264698_biz@gmail.com ">  
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Alice's Weekly Digest">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="DIG Weekly">  
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">  
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://localhost/check.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://google.co.in">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00">  
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">  
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">  

    <!-- Display the payment button. -->  
    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="btn_subscribe_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">  
    <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >  
</form>
```

In this case your notify url where paypal will send ipn is `http://localhost/check.php`.

So put that code in `check.php` page. After recieving the ipn you can further use it to enter in your database etc.

or visit this link to get an overview of paypal ipn listener:

https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNImplementation

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. i've mentioned where to add all that ipn listener code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use notify_url for paypal to send a IPN response to a script on your site when a payment is made. Use this hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="yourwebsite.com/paypal/process" />
```

Now when a user pays, paypal will send a IPN to your website.

For the Return,  you can use:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="path.to/return/website/"/> // After successful payment
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value=""/> // If user cancels where to redirect to.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set paypal notify_url(IPN Response url) and success url like this way:

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://localhost/demo/payment.php/ipn_response">                                            
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/demo/payment_successful">
```

Get Paypal response paypal.php

```
     function ipn($ipn_data) {

    define('SSL_P_URL', 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    define('SSL_SAND_URL', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    $hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if (!preg_match('/paypal\.com$/', $hostname)) {
        $ipn_status = 'Validation post isn\'t from PayPal';
        if ($ipn_data == true) {
            //You can send email as well
        }
        return false;
    }

    // parse the paypal URL
    $paypal_url = ($_REQUEST['test_ipn'] == 1) ? SSL_SAND_URL : SSL_P_URL;
    $url_parsed = parse_url($paypal_url);

    $post_string = '';
    foreach ($_REQUEST as $field => $value) {
        $post_string .= $field . '=' . urlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';
    }
    $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command
    // get the correct paypal url to post request to
    $paypal_mode_status = $ipn_data; //get_option('im_sabdbox_mode');
    if ($paypal_mode_status == true)
        $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);
    else
        $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);

    $ipn_response = '';

    if (!$fp) {
        // could not open the connection. If loggin is on, the error message
        // will be in the log.
        $ipn_status = "fsockopen error no. $err_num: $err_str";
        if ($ipn_data == true) {
            echo 'fsockopen fail';
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        // Post the data back to paypal
        fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Content-length: " . strlen($post_string) . "\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
        fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n");

        // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
        }
        fclose($fp); // close connection
    }
    // Invalid IPN transaction. Check the $ipn_status and log for details.
    if (!preg_match("/VERIFIED/s", $ipn_response)) {
        $ipn_status = 'IPN Validation Failed';

        if ($ipn_data == true) {
            echo 'Validation fail';
            print_r($_REQUEST);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        $ipn_status = "IPN VERIFIED";
        if ($ipn_data == true) {
            echo 'SUCCESS';
            print_r($_REQUEST);
        }
        return true;
    }
}

function ipn_response() {
    //mail("sobhagya1411@gmail.com","My subject",print_r($request,true));
    $ipn_data = true;
    if ($this->ipn($_REQUEST)) {
        $this->insert_data($_REQUEST);
    }
}

function issetCheck($post, $key) {
    if (isset($post[$key])) {
        $return = $post[$key];
    } else {
        $return = '';
    }
    return $return;
}


 public function insert_data(){

     $post = $_REQUEST;    

    $item_name= $this->issetCheck($post, 'item_name');         
    $amount = $this->issetCheck($post, 'mc_gross');
    $currency = $this->issetCheck($post, 'mc_currency');
    $payer_email = $this->issetCheck($post, 'payer_email');
    $first_name = $this->issetCheck($post, 'first_name');
    $last_name = $this->issetCheck($post, 'last_name');
    $country = $this->issetCheck($post, 'residence_country');
    $txn_id = $this->issetCheck($post, 'txn_id');
    $txn_type = $this->issetCheck($post, 'txn_type');
    $payment_status = $this->issetCheck($post, 'payment_status');
    $payment_type = $this->issetCheck($post, 'payment_type');
    $payer_id = $this->issetCheck($post, 'payer_id');
    $create_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $payment_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $paypal_sql = "INSERT INTO ipn_data_tbl (item_name,payer_email,first_name,last_name,amount,currency,country,txn_id,txn_type,payer_id,payment_status,payment_type,create_date,payment_date)
    VALUES ($item_name,'$payer_email','$first_name','$last_name','$amount','$currency','$country','$txn_id','$txn_type','$payer_id','$payment_status','$payment_type','$create_date','$payment_date')";
    mysql_query($paypal_sql); 

}
```