# PayPal integration - instant payment notification (IPN)

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am having doubts on how to implement PayPal IPN. I have created a button, and it has the variable notify_url defined:

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="./ipn.php" />
```

In ipn.php file I have put this code (from [Integrate paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188644/integrate-paypal/7188682#7188682)):

```
<?php
// read the post from paypal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to paypal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "content-length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

if (!$fp) {
    // HTTP ERROR
} else {
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            // check the payment_status is "completed"
            // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
            // check that receiver_email is your primary paypal email
            // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
            // process payment
        }
        else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
            // log for manual investigation
        }
    }
    fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

The question is how do I receive the notifications in the user's account? What kind of code do I need additionally?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on IPN? It doesn't sound like you have a grasp on how it works yet: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Comment: You're going to need to use a full path to your URL including https://yourdomain.com.